# docker multiple containers with static addresses

Tags: static, ip, docker

I am working on a project usually implemented with VMs. But I would like to hack with docker containers instead, in order to practice and learn something new.

So here is what I would like to do : create several containers running on the same host, with static ip addresses, connected one to each others (but not necessarily connected to the outside world).
In other words, I would like emulate kind of a stand alone network, composed of several computers connected to the same switch.

I tried to change /etc/network/interfaces in containers to set static ip addresses for eth0, docker0, ... But it doesn't affect the system in any way. I tried to use --net=host, --cap-add=NET_ADMIN but it didn't help.

It's driving me crazy. SOS!
Thanks

EDIT :
Important stuff I didn't say : I'm using my Mac Book Air, and I am running boot2docker (which creates a VM running docker).
When I run an image with "docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash", I don't have docker0 as an interface : running "ip a" in the container displays only lo and eth0.

Answer (score 2):

Why did you try `--net=host`? This option disables network isolation at all, and runs container in default network namespace. This means that docker containers can see all host network interfaces. I think this is not your option.

There is important to tell, how docker deals with isolated networks. First of all, it creates bridge named `docker0` (at least by default). Each time when you starting container with isolated network (i.e., without `--net=host`), docker creates a pair of `veth` interfaces. One of this interface docker gives to container (if you'll run `ip link list` in your container, you will see exactly this *virtual* interface). Another one docker plugs in bridge `docker0` (by the way, you can say which bridge to use by passing "-b ${BRIDGE}" option to docker daemon).

I'd recommend you to read [article about docker bridges](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/) and [this one about network namespaces](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/).

Try to run containers with isolated networking, and then assign static IP that you like. But be aware of routing - host must have route to subnet, where your containers running. Easiest way to do this (and the only adequate as for me) - assign to you containers IP from same subnet as docker bridge.

Following example works well for me.

```
user@host$ ip addr
docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 56:84:7a:fe:97:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.42.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5484:7aff:fefe:9799/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@docker-1# ip addr
eth0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


root@docker-2# ip addr
eth0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.3/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Oh yeah, how did you try to assign IP to your container? Just modification of `/etc/network/interfaces` will not works because nobody can apply this config for you. After container startup you should use `ifdown` and `ifup` tools to configure interface according your configuration.

Comment: Hi Viacheslav, thanks for answering so quickly. So I tried -net=host because what I had so far wasn't working, so I tried everything I found, including this. Let's read those articles you advised me. Thanks again

Comment: I assigned using /etc/network/interfaces : 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 10.0.2.50
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 10.0.2.100
 broadcast 10.0.2.255

But then, using "ifdown eth0" gives : "ifdown: interface eth0 not configured". Which I don't understand since "ip a" in the container gives me "inet 172.17.0.3/16 scope global eth0" for eth0 (and nothing about docker0...)

Comment: Yep, my mistake. ifdown will not deconfigure this interface since interface has been configured by docker but not `ifup`. You may just run `ifup eth0`. After that your eth0 will have two ip addresses. Also you can remove old IP address using `ip addr del ${OLD_ADDRESS} dev eth0`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. So I tried ifup, but I got the same error as the other day : root@758da37c06e7:/# ifup eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
Failed to bring up eth0. /// I get the same error "RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted" when I try "root@758da37c06e7:/# ip addr del 172.17.0.4/16 dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted" before.

Comment: Sounds like you forget give CAP_NETADMIN capability to container.

Comment: Ok, it's improving, I don't have permission issues any more, except that "File exists"... : so using --cap-add=NET_ADMIN, I get this : root@90535099fe66:/# ifdown eth0
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
root@90535099fe66:/# ifup eth0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0. And I still can't change the ip.